# Is there a way to prevent the editing of HTML and CSS contents in a page using Firebug-like tools?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Is there a way to prevent the editing of HTML and CSS contents in a page using Firebug-like tools?

I found that some users are editing some values in hidden fields and some contents which written between a div or span tag for gaining some profits. They are doing mostly by editing with help of tools like firebug. Is there any way to identify such modifications? The problem here is that the values they are editing is generated when the page is compiled. The page is developed in PHP. The editing is done mostly in between the  and  tags.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: First rule of networked (including, but not limited to, web) application design: _Never_ trust the client. You have no control over what data will be sent to you, so you can expect to receive altered, invalid, and/or malicious submissions on a regular basis.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no way to prevent users from changing the information that is submitted from *their* browser to your server. You do not have control over their browser.

To fix this problem, you must change the design of your server application so that sensitive information that users should not modify, is not sent to the browser and submitted back to you.

The following is a simple example. Suppose you have an online store and are implementing an "Order" button. Suppose you have a form like this:

```
<form action="/order">
    <input type="hidden" name="description" value="Better Mousetrap">
    <input type="hidden" name="price" value="15.00">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

If you have a form like the above, the user could change the `price` value to whatever they want when submitting the form. That is probably not what you want. Instead, you could do something like:

```
<form action="/order">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="1234">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Then, when this form is submitted, you look up `item_id` number 1234 in your database, and get the price from that. The only thing the user could change in this case is the `item_id`, which means they would get a different item than what they wanted.

Comment: Expanding: if it's not a price but a session or user specific value, you can store that value and assign a token to the transaction, then pass that token to client, just like item_id on the example above. That way you can recognice the values by the token you received.